# Who can tell me how to compile webkitdotnet

Tags: webkit

I downloaded the latest package in this url:
https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet

but I can't compile it in vs2008 or vs2005,who can tell me how to compile it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could start by checking out the [instructions](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/building.php) put out by the `webkitdotnet` team.

From TFA:

> Open webkitdotnet/WebKit.NET.sln in Visual Studio 2008, or equivalent,
>   and select 'Build -> Build Solution' from the menu. If you wish to try
>   the test web browser application, right-click the WebKitBrowserTest
>   project in the Solution Explorer and select 'Set as Startup Project',
>   then select 'Debug -> Start Without Debugging' from the menu. The
>   compiled library can be found in a subdirectory of webkitdotnet/bin.

Comment: Oh,sorry,I forgeted I compiled it in vs2008,but can't built it.